# wifi disconnected after reboot and install RT3290 better wifi driver xubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, ralink

Problem with weak wifi signal. I found the risen and solution [here](http://onthim.blogspot.de/2015/06/install-ralink-rt3290-wi-fi-driver-on.html) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771882/rt3290-wifi-not-working-ubuntu-16-04) the signal after installing the new driver is much better, but after re-boot or new start my wifi don't work.
Should I do something in another way in XFCE?
I kan solve it actually only manually with 2 commands:

```
sudo ifconfig rename3 up
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

1. If the new driver was installed, must be uninstalled (run `uninstall.sh`)
2. Upgrade the kernel by executing the below command after connecting to internet over LAN or USB:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
   ```
3. Install a new driver (`run.sh`)